# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' building a package with click

Tags: python, pip, click, python-click

Hello I am trying to building a python package I have the following folder structure

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── setup.py
└── vms-backup
    ├── commands
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── to_csv.py
    │   ├── to_sql.py
    │   └── upload_to_s3.py
    └── __init__.py
```

the setup.py contains the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import pipfile

pf = pipfile.load("Pipfile")

setup(
    name="vms-backup",
    version="1.0.0",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    python_requires="==3.8.13",
    install_requires=["click"],
    entry_points="""
        [console_scripts]
        vms-backup=vms-backup:cli
    """,
)
```

and vms-backup/.**init**.py

```
import click
from commands import to_csv, to_sql, upload_to_s3


@click.group()
def cli():
    pass


cli.add_command(to_csv)
cli.add_command(to_sql)
cli.add_command(upload_to_s3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

The code works perfectly if I execute, but when executing pip install -e . in order to test the entry_points I got the following output:

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in vms-backup setup command: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Any idea about what is wrong with the code?

Thanks

**EDIT**

If I execute inside a dockerfile the error change:

```
backup_1        | Obtaining file:///usr/app
backup_1        |   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
backup_1        |   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
backup_1        |   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
backup_1        |   
backup_1        |   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
backup_1        |   │ exit code: 1
backup_1        |   ╰─> [1 lines of output]
backup_1        |       error in vms-backup setup command: ("EntryPoint must be in 'name=module:attrs [extras]' format", 'vms-backup=vms-backup:cli')
backup_1        |       [end of output]
backup_1        |   
backup_1        |   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
backup_1        | error: metadata-generation-failed
backup_1        | 
backup_1        | × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
backup_1        | ╰─> See above for output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say your problem is that the package name `vms-backup` uses a dash.
Try with `vms_backup` (or `vmsbackup`).

The command name can stay the same: `vms-backup = vms_backup:cli`